# Calculating pitch and roll from XYZ accelerometer data collected from a wildlife collar

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, rotations, mathematical-biology

I work with wildlife collars (lions, elephants) which also collect XYZ accelerometer data. From this, I can visualize pitch and roll of the animals in the collar manufacturers web application, but they have not made this data available to download. I can only download the raw XYZ accelerometer data. The manufacturer has specified that the accelerometers are on 2G and has max value of 32 000 and minimum of -32 000.  but I am not sure what that refers to.

Ideally, I would like to be able to find a formula that allows me to convert the XYZ data to pitch and roll in Excel, if possible. I have looked at some online tutorials and forums (Arduino) but so far have not been able to find anything that works.

One of the formulas I tried is:
`roll = atan2(y_Buff , z_Buff) * 57.3; pitch = atan2((- x_Buff) , sqrt(y_Buff * y_Buff + z_Buff * z_Buff)) * 57.3;`
But the pitch and roll data it returns is very different compared to what I can see in the web-based portal.

For example:

| X | Y | Z | Roll from formula | Pitch from formula | Actual roll | Actual pitch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1626 | 11908 | 9991 | 40.00013 | 95.97879 | 5.97 | -0.01 |

Comment: The $\pm 32000$ almost certainly refers to the resolution of the Analog to Digital Converter being used.  16 bit of resolution with get you approximately there.

Comment: They are very likely doing some low pass filtering before calculating the roll and pitch.

Comment: Do you have a device that you can setup in a lab and get the output for specific orientations?

Comment: @Tpofofn No I'm afraid I don't have access to a device I can setup in lab conditions

Comment: The values that you posted of actual pitch being lamost 0 don't square with the x value being so large.  Perhaps your device is setup with a "null" or "baseline" orientation.  I.e. you put the devide on an animal and put them in a standard pose then set that to the 0 pitch and 0 roll.  Perhaps that is what you are seeing.

Comment: The actual pitch value might be off; I have no way of verifying unless I am next to the animal. The collars come pre-programmed, we don't do anything to them when we get them/place them on the animal.